# Need to display trend analysis for 3 years for selected months in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have Data Limiting Expression as below for one Month Selected from Drop Down Property Control:

If('${Month}'='',true,If(Find('${Month}', String([Fiscal Month]))=1,TRUE,FALSE))

Where ${Month} is my dropdown property control to select a month. 
what if i want to display the data for last 6 months from the selected month.

(Concept: Im doing trend analysis for last 3 years. 
User will have oppurtunity to select any month from dropdown
and the comparison analysis(of years)  of last 6 months from selected month will be displayed.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is month a string month like 'October' or is it a month number like 10? Also, do you have a different column that has a full date that you could simply extract the month from?

Comment: Month is displayed as String in Dropdown. Yes, i do have a separate column that has full date.